# nhibernate envers: auditing an entity already in production

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

We have an application that is already in production and it is using Envers to do auditing.

Now we are going to release an update in which we audit a new kind of entity. However this entity already exists in the production environment, only it was not audited so far.

We have tried in a test environment containing existings records, and it crashes upon saving because Envers cannot find a previous revision for the entity being saved.

What is the approach to takle this issue ?

It would be great for instance if one could specify the date from which an entity should be audited.

Comment: Are you using the `validity audit strategy`?

Comment: yes, we are using this strategy.

Comment: If I recall correctly the last time I used Envers in 2012, the validity audit strategy throws an exception but the default strategy does not. I think you may need to manually insert data into the relevant audit table for the entity to provide Envers a starting revision to work with, based on what the validity audit strategy does as described here - http://envers.bitbucket.org/

Comment: that's not good :( We have many entities potentially impacted since we use REVCHANGES to track all changes. I would have thought there would be an easier way than scripting....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to, manually, write a script for this. Shouldn't be that hard, just create a single row in your revision table and write "insert audit records" for this revision for all your audited entities.